# put checkmark in pdfmake report

Tags: pdfmake

i have a project to print out the working report. i got trouble when putting check mark inside pdfmake generated report i follow some instructions from below link :

- https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side
- https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/948

i already follow all the instructions there but my fontelo nor fontawesome icon show up in my report. while using fontawesome. the icon show square block no the real icon. hope someone can help me figure this out thanks

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you could include some code (a minimal docDefinition, and the printer part).

My code, using fontawesome to display checkboxes/radio icons :

The printer part :

```
var fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'assets/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
    },
    FontAwesome: {
        normal: 'assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'
    }
  };
// ...
var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
```

---

And the docDefinition. You can **try using the unicode code** :

```
var dd = {
  content: { text: "\uf046   ", style: 'fontawesome' },
  styles: {
    fontawesome: {
      'font': 'FontAwesome',
      'color': "#656565"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this logic, server side on my app. Using the correct unicode was key for making this work.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this ASCII value could work for you? √√√√√√√√

- Mac: Option + v
- Windows10: Alt + 251

You will get this symbol √ which is similar to the tick checkmark.

- http://pdfmake.org/playground
- Look at the `Extended ASCII Codes` section: http://www.asciitable.com/

```
{
   text: '√',
   absolutePosition: { x: 21, y: 293 }
}
```

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: This is what worked for me without any difficulties, thanks for this check-mark √ 

Answer (score 3):

you can use `canvas` to draw the square for checkmark as below

```
canvas: [
            {
                type: 'polyline',
                lineWidth: 1,
                closePath: true,
                points: [{ x: 0, y: 0}, { x: 8, y: 0 }, { x: 8, y: 8 }, { x: 0, y:8 }]
            }
        ]
```

and then use it with `column` to make it look like checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a image next to a text like I did here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdfmake-example-3f14km?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts